# Instalar Entity Framework Core, Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

Estoy tratando de Instalar EntityFrameworkCore, pero ni por al administrador de paquetes ni por la linea de comandos lo puedo hacer, ya probé reinstalando Visual Studio 2022. el comando completo es "dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" (Estoy siguiendo este tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias

Comment: Tienes que usar el comando en la terminal / CMD / Poweshell lo que sea que uses. [Instalación de Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/get-started/overview/install). Aunque acabo de ver que ya lo intentaste, checa si no hay una actualización de Windows pendiente.

Comment: tenes una instalacion standard de nuget? estas detras de un proxy? puedes encontrar otros paquetes nuget?